# OpenSSL EAP-TLS handshake using BIO

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, x509

i'm trying to achieve a EAP-TLS handshake using the OpenSSL C library, but with memory BIOs. I succeeded in achieving a client hello as:

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
readbytes = BIO_read(wbio, buf, BUF_SIZ);
```

and sending buf through a socket. Next, the server sent me a TLS_server_hello message, which I tried to load into the same ssl structure used above as:

`readbytes = BIO_write(rbio, temp, bytes);` and calling `SSL_do_handshake(ssl)` again. But when I try to isolate the key-exchange section of the server's message, or the certificate chain, which I tried as:

```
X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
char cname = cert->name;
```

But it does not work. Am I doing something wrong when copying the buffer into the SSL structure? Am I atleast on the right track? Or is this data supposed to be handled differently? Thank you!

Comment: What does `SSL_do_handshake` return? Did you get a 1 back per [`SSL_do_handshake`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_do_handshake.html)? Also, [`SSL_get_peer_certificate`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html) will return `NULL` if there is no certificate. No certificate is expected if anonymous ciphers are used (otherwise, no certificate *should* be an error raised by the app (the library will *not* raise the error)). Do you know if a cert is expected in EAP-TLS?